# Does the Kuntres Yeshivas Eretz Yisroel exist?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, jewish-books, eretz-yisrael

In the Eim Habonim Smeichah, the Mishnah Sachir makes many references to a Kuntres Yeshivas Eretz Yisroel by a certain R' Yonah Dov Blumberg from Dvinsk. Is this kuntres in publication? Is anyone familiar with where I can get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it's still in publication, however it is available at hebrewbooks here: https://hebrewbooks.org/33954

If you want a hard copy it also seems to be for sale here:
https://il.bidspirit.com/ui/lotPage/source/catalog/auction/6535/lot/131167/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A1-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0-%D7%97?lang=en

Though I don't know the site firsthand and can't vouch for it.

Comment: I have ordered many things from them. The actual on-demand printer is Lulu.com. My suggestion is to look over the PDF from the print copy on the link. If it is legible to you, order. It will take a couple of weeks before you receive the sefer. I prefer hardcover. If the book arrives not as expected, my experience is that they will work to replace it with a good copy.

Comment: I don’t know about the Bidspirit link. I order from the linked website at Hebrew books.com. They are connected with Shaftek, who is a frum guy in Baltimore (I believe).